# RoR: accessing page generated in after_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, pdfkit

I'm having a problem understanding the after_save rails callback. There is a snippet from my model:

```
  after_save :log_creation

  private 

    def log_creation
      logger.info "RECEIVED => #{ self.name } - #{ self.value } - #{ self.id }"
      path_to_url = url_for({ :host => "localhost:8080", :action=>"show", :controller=>"testing", :format =>"pdf", :id => self })
      logger.info path_to_url
      file = open(path_to_url, "r").read
      logger.info file
    end
```

In the development log I get the expected information for the first two logger.info. The third one I don't get it, because I receive a 404 exception (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound).

So, what I'm doing wrong?

The PDF generation works OK (using PDFkit), if I comment the after_save line and try to access the URL it's OK, but when I try to access it on after_save it doesn't work as I excepected.

All of this is for sending an email (with a mailer) with a PDF attached on it. It would download the PDF (through the controlled) and then send it.

Comment: I don't really understand what is working or not, but shouldn't you use :id => self.id instead of :id => self ?

Comment: @mb14 the problem is with the line 'file = open(path_to_url, "r").read '. The url_for line works fine - I see it in the log and it's the expected one.

Comment: what does your `path_to_url` look like in your log ? may just be a problem of relative address. I think File.open works on your local filesystem context, so if your path starts with "/" you're actually trying to find a file from the root of the filesystem. A trailing slash may be confusing, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem has to do with transactions. The new model has been saved, but the transaction hasn't ended yet. Try `after_commit` instead of `after_save`. See [the documentation on callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for details about all the different callbacks.